# Unimplemented console API: undefined, error in Visual Studio Code debugging

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

After updating my Windows, I am now encountering an error while debugging Ionic App on Visual Studio Code. Every time it passes the statement console.log, it prints the error "Unimplemented console API: undefined".
Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Which extension are you using to debug the Ionic app? The Chrome debugging extension?

Comment: same problem here ! Have you found a solution  ?

Comment: @RobLourens, installed extensions are: 1. C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)
2. Cordova Tools Extension

Comment: I recommend filing a bug with the cordova extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in vscode-chrome-debug as pointed out by [Jimmy Thomson](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova/issues/201#issuecomment-257056099) on there Github Issue page!

Here is the Dirty fix by Jimmy Thomson:

1. Go to your vscode extension directory, either C:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ or ~/.vscode/extensions, then go to vsmobile.cordova-tools-1.2.3/node_modules/vscode-chrome-debug-core/out/src/chrome/ and open up consoleHelper.js.
2. Look around line 37 for outputText = 'Unimplemented console API: ' +
   m.type;
3. change that to outputText = 'Unimplemented console API: ' + JSON.stringify(m);

Answer (score 0):

Well guys. I was also like you getting this error but I found the easiest method to solve the problem. I have just installed a extension named code runner from the market place. After installing just right click the javascript file and you can see a option named "run code". Click that and everything will run as cake.